# Accessing and Updating External Databases From Salesforce

Tags: rest, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I need to connect Salesforce to an external database we have, and constantly keep both the database and salesforce updated in as close to real time as we can get. I have tired Google searching possible solutions, but nearly all of them have been outdated by over a year. Any ideas?

Thank You!

Comment: Are you doing bi-directional sync or one way from Salesforce to DB only?

Comment: @GarethJordan sorry for the delay, bi-directional sync

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your exact scenario it is quite difficult to give you a proper answer.

However off the top of my head I would suggest two Salesforce products.

1. Salesforce Connect

https://www.salesforce.com/products/platform/products/salesforce-connect/

Salesforce Connect allows you to connect to various data sources and turn the tables / objects of that data source into a SObject. For example MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle etc. There are limitations and thus it would be better to talk to a Certified Architect about such an implementation.

2. Heroku Connect

https://www.heroku.com/connect

Heroku Connect allows you to connect a Heroku data source with a Salesforce Object. The sync is not immediate but there are quite a few customisations inside the product to make the sync as "live" as possible. There are limitations and thus it would be better to talk to a Certified Architect about such an implementation.

Comment: For Salesforce Connect (which I would recommend) ensure your DB supports oData 4.0 for read/write capability if you want bi-directional sync of data. oData 2.0 adapter only supports read of external DB.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Connect has limitations.. It's good for presenting data via the interface, but if you need to act on the data and report on the data it might not be the best bet.

For close to real time hand coded sync, look at the streaming API, or using Salesforce Platform Events.

If you want to use an ETL tool, my organization has had decent luck with DBAmp, which is a Sql add on product and fairly inexpensive as compared to a lot of ETL tools ($1625 annually.) http://www.forceamp.com/  We're able to replicate the entire SF database offline in SQL with DBAMP, push changes to the offline Sql copy and upsert changes. It's also a good backup solution via offline full data copy. We got very good support from them as well when we encountered challenges.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This comment is out of date now. SF Connect supports much more functionality nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are syncing one object or multiple objects but there are a few options that you have.

- You can try the salesforce provided features Salesforce Connect which allows you to view and update data from your external source In salesforce but there are limitations with reporting and other [considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_connect_considerations.htm&type=5) you should consider.
- If you make use of Heroku, [Heroku Connect](https://www.heroku.com/connect) is your best bet
- You can also use a middleware ESB solutions like MuleSoft which can orchestrate keeping data in sync across multiple data sources and do batch loads, but depending on how often changes you want to keep an eye out for api limits for inbound calls to salesforce.
- You can roll your own solution where you can use [Outbound Messages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging.htm) in workflow (or triggers that initiates an apex class that calls out, but that is more cumbersome and you have to do custom error handling and retry logic which you get for free using outbound messages) to send changes from salesforce to your homegrown service that writes to you database and have you homegrown solution write back to salesforce using the soap or rest api.  That would probably take you some time to build. You would also still need to be aware of API limits depending on how many updates are made on the non salesforce side.

  - You crate a Canvas App which displays data from your DB in Salesforce as a Tab and hook it up via SSO so users are auto logged in.  But again there would not be reporting, or any salesforce features that you can take advantage of.

But I really think that you should spend some time to determine what system is your source of truth because that would determine how the data should be synced.  You should also investigate if you **really** need the sync to be realtime or near realtime, or if you can manage with something like an hourly true up on the system that is not the source of truth.